# Facebook iOS SDK Feed Dialog issue after authentication

Tags: ios, facebook, ios5, xcode4.2

I seem to be having an issue with the feed dialog, which I haven't had before.
I suspect it's because of iOS 5, but I'm not sure.

If the user needs authentication, he's being redirected to the Facebook app, and then returns to my app.

Afterwards, the user clicks a "Share" button, and the feed dialog **appears**.
But suddenly, it **disappears**.

If the user clicks "Share" again, the feed dialog is working just fine. It's just that first time, after returning to the app from authentication...

The code associated with the "Share" button is simply this:

```
if ([facebook isSessionValid]) {
   [facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
}
```

The *params* variable is always set to the correct values and is not nil.
If the session is not valid, the user is being sent to the authentication method.

I tried also to comment out an IF Statement in FBDialog.m which I've read somewhere, but it didn't work out.

Anyone experienced the same issue?

Thanks!

***EDIT:***
I'm pretty sure it's because of iOS 5 now, since I've built the project on my iPad 2, which is running iOS 4.3, and it works fine from the first time.

***EDIT 2:***
It's suddenly working fine. ...and I didn't change anything O_O

Comment: I'm seeing exactly this issue on iOS 5.0 also

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and this code change fixed it https://github.com/deyton/facebook-ios-sdk/commit/c1d3702f7c2042549c3bee050ceade7fb6f593a4