# iOS Facebook Publish Feed Dialog doesn't show up after authentication

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

Thanks for reading.

I went through [Facebook iOS SDK Feed Dialog issue after authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937089/facebook-ios-sdk-feed-dialog-issue-after-authentication) but in vain.

**What works:**
I created a sample "Hello, World" app using the [Facebook iOS Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/) with the Feed Dialog. This tutorial works fine and I am able to see the post in my feed.

**Problem:**
When I integrated this code in my app, I don't get to see the Feed Dialog after the authentication when the control reaches back to my app.

**Flow of control:**
I have a `UIImagePickerController` showing a camera that takes a picture, then shows `UIAlertView` to indicate that the image is being uploaded, shows a `UIAlertView` to display the result returned from server, and then finally shows a `UIActionSheet` to display the different sharing options (share to Facebook, Twitter, etc.).

When the user hits "Share to Facebook", the following `selector` gets invoked:

```
- (void) initFacebook
{
    //Init Facebook
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"308136969223987" andDelegate:self];

    //Check for access_token 
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"]
       && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

    if(![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        [facebook authorize:nil];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  kAppId, @"app_id",
  @"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/", @"link",
  @"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg", @"picture",
  @"Facebook Dialogs", @"name",
  @"Reference Documentation", @"caption",
  @"Using Dialogs to interact with users.", @"description",
  @"Facebook Dialogs are so easy!",  @"message",
  nil];

  [_facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];  
}
```

This launches the Facebook app to authenticate, and then opens my app again with the `UIImagePickerController` but doesn't show the `Feed Dialog`.

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to manually call the method you want again, in your case -(void)initFacebook, in the -(void)fbDidLogin of the FBSessionDelegate.

In addition, to make this more generic, a little trick I did after [facebook authorize:nil]; I set a pending target and selector to store the pending command that needs to be executed after login. Something like this...

```
id fbPendingTarget;
SEL fbPendingAction;

    if (![delegate.facebook isSessionValid]) {
        [delegate.facebook authorize:nil]; // Facebook app or Safari login, mustitask

        // Save pending actions
        delegate.fbPendingTarget = self;
        delegate.fbPendingAction = @selector(facebookButtonPressed);

        [self retain]; // *** hold on to self if you will release self and is using fbPendingTarget as self
    }
```

and when the delegate fires, it runs your pending action ...

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    [self storeAuthData:[facebook accessToken] expiresAt:[facebook expirationDate]];
    [self apiFQLIMe]; // request user info

    // perform any pending actions after login
    if ([fbPendingTarget respondsToSelector:fbPendingAction]) {
        [fbPendingTarget performSelector:fbPendingAction];
    }
    self.fbPendingTarget = nil;
    self.fbPendingAction = nil;

    [self release]; // *** let go of self after we finished everything
}
```

This help executing any pending actions you need after login. And don't forget to clear them after executing or login failed.

```
-(void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cannot Connect"
                                                         message:@"There was an error while connecting to Facebook. Please try Again."
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
    [alertView show];

    self.fbPendingTarget = nil;
    self.fbPendingAction = nil;

    [self release]; // *** let go of self after we finished everything
}
```

Hope this helps :)

**Edit:** I find it better to set `fbPendingTarget` to some object that exists throughout the app lifetime (like `appDelegate`) rather than setting to `self`. This is because in many cases your `self` is a view that will be released right after the user sends a post to Facebook. Sending a message to a released object will crash your app.

A dirty way to get around this is to explicitly use `[self retain]` before sending and then `[self release]` in your `fbPendingAction`. But that would retain everything else that should be released in self by that time. I just find it easier to set to `appDelegate` since most action you will do is just displaying an alert anyway. I'll edit the code just for safety sake.